# Decompiling the contract with keccak function

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, storage, keccak

Currently, I'm researching how to construct the solidity version from the bytecode. However, I try to understand how keccak works, but I'm not sure about the parameters (such as the below code)

So, could you help me to understand what "memory[temp4 + 0x20:temp4 + 0x20 + memory[temp4:temp4 + 0x20]]" stand for? (I guess it's combined of address of sender, some data that stored at 0x24, and ????)

Many thanks

```
                        if (storage[0x00] != 0x02) {
                            storage[0x00] = 0x02;
                            var temp2 = memory[0x40:0x60];
                            memory[temp2 + 0x20:temp2 + 0x20 + 0x20] = msg.sender; #2-4
                            memory[temp2 + 0x40:temp2 + 0x40 + 0x20] = storage[0x24]; #4-6
                            var temp3 = temp2 + 0x60;
                            var temp4 = memory[0x40:0x60];
                            memory[temp4:temp4 + 0x20] = temp3 - temp4 - 0x20;
                            memory[0x40:0x60] = temp3;
                            #
                            if (var3 == keccak256(memory[temp4 + 0x20:temp4 + 0x20 + memory[temp4:temp4 + 0x20]]))
```

Comment: How did you generate that bytecode? `memory[0x40:0x60]` is the free memory pointer. It appears to be hashing `msg.sender` and `storage[0x24]` into `var3`.

Comment: This bytecode was not generated by me. I randomly picked a contract on the network and try to decompile and understand it. So, you mean the parameters of keccak are only msg.sender and storage[0x24]?

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze the code

```
var temp2 = memory[0x40:0x60];
```

Now temp2 points to free memory

```
memory[temp2 + 0x20:temp2 + 0x20 + 0x20] = msg.sender; #2-4
```

Copy `msg.sender` to `temp2[0x20:0x40]`

```
memory[temp2 + 0x40:temp2 + 0x40 + 0x20] = storage[0x24]; #4-6
```

Copy `storage[0x24]` to `temp2[0x40:0x60]`

```
var temp3 = temp2 + 0x60;
```

Now `temp3` points to the end of the used area

```
var temp4 = memory[0x40:0x60];
```

`temp4` = `temp2` points to the start of the free memory

```
memory[temp4:temp4 + 0x20] = temp3 - temp4 - 0x20;
```

It stores `0x40 = temp3 - temp4 - 0x20` into `temp2[0:0x20]`

```
memory[0x40:0x60] = temp3;
```

Updates free memory pointer to point after the buffer.

Comment: Thank you, it's pretty clear. However, why do we need the line: ```It stores 0x40 = temp3 - temp4 - 0x20 into temp2[0:0x20]```?

I think it is not a parameter for hashing